# Start app on whatever (empty) NFC attached

Tags: android, tags, nfc, intentfilter

I have already tried probably 100 different way to accomplish it. I just can't figure out how to do this.

I have an empty NFC tag. I need only to start the app if my phone scans an NFC tag, no matter what tag it is, or what is written on it. I don't want to write something on it, or read it.

At the moment, if I scan an NFC tag, my phone opens the Android built-in NFC reader.

If my app is opened, it detects scanning the NFC tag. But I want to start the app by scanning the tag.

Here is my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Note that I tried different ways to start the app...it didn't work once.

Let me know, if you need my MainActivity. Note that my MainActivity is not started on launch. I have a splashscreen activity before it.

Is it even possible? And, is it possible to start app via service or kind of it?

Comment: maybe it will sound stupid but there are few devices that not have nfc like one plus two, on which device you test your code?

Comment: S6 edge plus, device has nfc. As i wrote above, it works when app is opened, then i can perform stuff. But not when app is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch events for any (empty or non-empty) tags using the `TECH_DISCOVERED` intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
           android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

Note that intent filters must be enclosed withing `<activity>...</activity>` tags. The `<meta-data>` tag must be outside the intent-filter tag but also withing the activity tag.

Moreover, you need a tech filter file (`xml/nfc_tech_filter.xml`) that properly lists all the tag technologies that you want to filter for:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcBarcode</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

Since other technologies like `Ndef` and `IsoDep` operate on top of those basic tag technologies above (`NfcA`, `NfcB`, etc.) there is no need to specify them in the filter file as they are already covered by the basic tag technology.

Note that if you list multiple `<tech>` entries within one `<tech-list>` entry they are combined with logical AND while multiple `<tech-list>` entries are combined with logical OR.

The above will filter for both empty and non-empty tags with whatever technologies you list in the filter file. However, for non-empty, NDEF-formatted tags, any `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter (from your app or any other app) that matches the data-type on the tag will take precedence over the `TECH_DISCOVERED` intent filter. Consequently your app won't be notified in those cases. If you also want to receive events for such tags, you need to register an `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter with the appropriate data-type. E.g. if the data-type is the URL http://www.example.com/

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Finally, try to avoid using the `TAG_DISCOVERED` intent filter. This is meant as a fall-back and will only be triggered if no other app is registered for that tag type.

Comment: It worked, now the popup  to choose my app comes up. Is it possible, to set it as default? I mean it let me choose between my app and build in nfc reader. But i can't tell, open always with...my app. Possible?

Comment: @Wladislaw No, TECH_DISCOVERED events cannot be assigned to one default app. All apps with a matching TECH_DISCOVERED intent filter will always be shown in an intent chooser. You can only overcome this by writing a custom NDEF record onto the tag and filtering for the data-type of that record.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple application, i only changed the manifest file to this:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Nothing changed for me, still the app is not opening...i am running android 6.